# Is there anyway to add a text message so it overlays on top of the image, like a watermark?

Tags: image, overlay, message, watermark, lightbox2

I am trying to add a text message on top of my Lightbox2 image.  I would like it to be centered in the image (and if possible at an angle like 30 or 45 degrees.  This will serve as a watermark to my websites users.  I am currently doing it with the regular message title which appears at the bottom of the Lightbox, but it is not as prominent as I would like it to be.  Any help would be appreciated.

I can create an additional overlay on the origional div. like this:



 Stock Image

But when I launch the lightbox, I can seem to find a way to get the overlay to work.